# isotope / masonry Horizontal to display only 2 rows of images and fill screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, image-gallery, photo-gallery, masonry

I'm working on my photo-portfolio with isotope and masonry Horizontal. I want to achieve following:

1) lets say I have 30 images in total and they are both portrait and landscape format

2) Thumbnails will be generated on the fly and I want them to display in 2 fixed height rows, but inside dynamic width columns

3) Lets say 20 thumbs have filled page within these 2 rows. So I don't want any other rows and scrollbars, but there will be "Next Page" button and onclick should display another page with remaining 10 thumbnails formatted same way as the previous page.

I'm looking at masonryHorizontal, CollagePlus (http://collageplus.edlea.com/ ), Mason JS (http://masonjs.com/ ), but still not sure how to draw correctly.

I would much appreciate if someone could help me on this or advice how to accomplish.

Thanks a lot!